# If two groups $G$ and $H$ both have a nonzero homomorphism to all other groups, and have only two idepotent homemorphisms, are they isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, integers, group-isomorphism

Consider to Groups $G$ and $H$ such that:

- The only two endo-hom  omorphisms (homomorphisms from a group to itself) that are idempotent (any function $f$ such that $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all x) are the maps that send each group element to itself, and the map that sends each element to the identity.
- For any other group $F$ (except the trivial group), there is a map from the group to $F$, such that not all the elements are mapped to $F$'s identity element.

Then $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic. Is this true?

On thing to notice is that $\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies this. Namely, if $F$ is a non trivial group, then it has a nonidentity element, a there is a map $f$ such that $f(1)=z$ for some nonidentity $z$ of $F$. Also note that the only endomorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}$ are multiplication by integers, and the only two integers such that $n^2=n$ are $0$ (which would create the map sending each element to the identity) and $1$ (which would create the element sending each element to itself.) Therefore the question above could be phrased by saying whether $G$ and $H$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

The motivation for this question is to see whether $\mathbb{Z}$ can be uniquely identified (up to isomorphism) based only on its homomorphisms.

Comment: Todd gave a sketch of an argument in the comments to the MO question.

Comment: Link [here](http://mathoverflow.net/a/194066/1770).  Summary: Pick a nonzero $p: G\to \mathbb{Z}$ (which can be chosen to be surjective), pick a $i:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ with $pi = 1$, then $ip: G\to G$ is idempotent, hence $1$.

Comment: @Slade How do you chose it to be surjective?

Comment: @PyRulez: Any nontrivial subgroup of Z is isomorphic to Z.

Comment: A ha, all the pieces are together in my mind. Time to put them together tomorrow (this question was part of a larger plan.)